# lookbehind combined with negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I to match in javascript any string after nomatch if any for example "test 1 test2"  in these 2 cases :

```
nomatch test1 test2
```

and

```
test1 test2
```

I tried https://regex101.com/r/qS4L1l/1

```
((?<=nomatch )\s*)(.+)|(?<!nomatch )(.+)
```

but it will include nomatch whereas I don't want to.

Comment: Just use: `/(?:\bnomatch\s+)?(.+)/` and grab capture group #1

Comment: Or, `(?<=nomatch\s+|^(?!.*nomatch\s)).+`, see https://regex101.com/r/Dl4VcR/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks I'll use yours as I need to do replace

Comment: You can use [a back-reference in replacement](https://regex101.com/r/qS4L1l/2)

Comment: What is the expected result if you have a string like `This is a nomatch test1 test2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target ECMAScript 2018+ compatible JavaScript environments, you can use

```
(?<=nomatch\s+|^(?!.*nomatch\s)).+
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xLX2ag/1). Here, any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible are matched only if they are immediately preceded with `nomatch` and then one more whitespaces, or, if the current position is the start of string and after that there is no `nomatch` substring with a whitespace after after any zero or more chars other than line break chars.

Since you need to replace the parts matched with `.+`, you can also consider using

```js
text.replace(/^(.*?nomatch\s+)?\S.*/, '$1<NEW TEXT>')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xLX2ag/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?nomatch\s+)?` - Group 1: an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, then `nomatch` and one or more whitespaces
- `\S` - a non-whitespace
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

The `$1` in the replacement string stands for the Group 1 value.

```js
const texts = ['This is a nomatch test1 test2','nomatch test1 test2','test1 test2'];
const re = /^(.*?nomatch\s+)?\S.*/;
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text.replace(re, '$1<NEW TEXT>'));
}
```